# To create a tar file inside a script

Tags: bash, tar

I am trying to create tar file inside a script by passing variables through some property file. Following are the commands:

```
cd $UNIXPATH
tar -cvf $TAR_NAME $BASEFOLDER
```

But when I am trying to run the script, it says:

```
tar: option requires an argument -- f
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
```

When I pass real values instead of variables, the script runs fine.
Can anyone help me through this issue.

Comment: The above syntax seems correct to me. Are you sure both variables are set? Also, you should quote your variables in case the filenamess contain whitespace or other special characters like `tar -cvf "$TAR_NAME" "$BASEFOLDER"` (probably won't fix this error though)

Comment: run script in debug mode.. using              set -x/+x  That will help to see the values used

Comment: Please edit your question to include more of the script, including the code that sets TAR_NAME and BASEFOLDER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably your $BASEFOLDER variable is empty might be one of the others though.

put these 2 lines just before the tar command and try it.

```
echo -e "PATH = $UNIXPATH\nTAR = $TAR_NAME\nBASE = $BASEFOLDER"
exit
```